# Interactions in regression and choosing appropriate model?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, interaction, model-comparison

I’m running the following regression model, where MR is a continuous predictor and grade, gender, and race are all categorical.

DV~MR + grade + gender + race

I’m also interested in how the 3 categorical predictors might moderate the effect of MR on the outcome measure. I'm not interested in how grade, gender, or race interact without MR. At minimum, I expect 2-way interactions between MR and the other predictors. In theory, I would also be interested in 3-way and 4-way interactions but it seems overly complex and inappropriate to include those in the model because I don't have strong hypotheses about those effects. How should I determine what interaction model to run?

Would it be appropriate to justify only including 2-way interaction terms in the model by doing the following model comparison? Or is this inappropriate because mod1 includes interactions that I don't care about (e.g., grade * female * race)?

```
mod1<-lm(DV~MR*grade*female*race, data = mydata)

mod2<-lm(DV~MR+grade+female+race+mrprop*grade+mrprop*female+mrprop*race, data = mydata)

anova(mod1, mod2)
```